# iOS 14.2 - No text notification when message is open but screen is off

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, notifications, bug

I think this issue started after upgrading to the new iOS.

- iPhone 11
- iOS 14.2

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Open Messages.
2. Open a specific person's message thread.
3. Lock your phone screen without closing the page.

**Expected**: The next time a text comes in from that person, you get the normal text notification via sound/banner/notification center.

**Actual**: The next time a text comes in from that person, you will **not** be notified via sound/banner/notification center.

4. Go back to the general Messages list of texts from all people OR go to the home screen and keep the app active OR close the app altogether.

**Expected & Actual**: The next time a text comes in from that person, you will get a text notification, like normal.

I want to know if anyone else has seen this issue and if they know of a way to resolve it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! :) Can you please edit your post to clarify what you're actually asking of us? At present it's only describing current behaviour and what your 'expected' behaviour is. If you were wanting to provide feedback to Apple, then you can do that [here](https://www.apple.com/feedback/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is a common bug that started early in iOS 14.2 beta and was never resolved for public release.](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSBeta/comments/jdck1m/intermittent_message_notifications_ios_142_beta_3/)

The workaround is always going back to the list of conversations before closing the Messages app, as you’ve already found.

[The beta release iOS 14.3 RC 2 reportedly resolves the issue](https://reddit.com/r/iOSBeta/comments/kakilr/ios_143_release_candidate_2_out_now/), so hopefully the issue will be resolved in the public release of iOS 14.3.